# Why is it not possible to see my public activity in an external runnable class?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-runonuithread

When the bluetooth connection turns on, I want to start a Therad which is checking for the available devices.
When starting this Thread, I want to start an other activity.
I created a public method with an intend to start the activity and now I want to call it from my Thread, but it isn't visable.

## MainActivity Content

```
 public Thread cConnectBT = new Thread();


    public void vBT_popup_start()
    {
        Handler hBT_popup_start = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        hBT_popup_start.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent tent_BT_popup_Start = new Intent (MainActivity.this, cBT_popup.class);
                startActivity(tent_BT_popup_Start);
            }
        });

    }
´´´

#Thread Content


´´´
public class cConnectBT implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
           vBT_popup_start();
        }

    }


}

´´´


vBT_popup_start();
is not visable, but why? how to fix that?
```

Comment: Maybe you define class cConnectBT outside the  MainActivity class. Check your closing bracket